# Convert Byte Array To File And Download

Tags: java

I am getting byte array from web service. this byte array is the pdf file. Below code execute well and download file on browser. But this file is seems corrupt. Also additional copy of file gets created on server which I am trying to avoid.

```
byte[] rawFile = myService.getDocument(param1, param2);    
          try (BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(rawFile));
               FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("myfile-1.pdf")) {
            byte dataBuffer[] = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = in.read(dataBuffer, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
              fileOutputStream.write(dataBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=myfile-1.pdf");
            response.flushBuffer();
          } catch (final Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
```

In a nutshell, below are 2 issue.

- Downloaded file (on browser) is seems corrupt and not open. Generic pdf error message appears.
- File which created on server is opening fine and shows content. But this file should not be physically present on server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Downloaded file (on browser) is seems corrupt and not open.

Because you never sent the file content to the browser.

> this file should not be physically present on server.

Then why did you explicitly write it there using `FileOutputStream`?

---

You need to write the file content to the `response`.

```
byte[] rawFile = myService.getDocument(param1, param2);

response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=myfile-1.pdf");
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
out.write(rawFile);
// no need to close or flush, that happens automatically when you return
```